# Why scala @tailrec can't be used on Option.flatMap?

Tags: scala, monads, tail-recursion

In scala, the following 2 functions serve exactly the same purpose:

```
@tailrec
final def fn(str: String): Option[String] = {
  Option(str).filter(_.nonEmpty).flatMap { v =>
    fn(v.drop(1))
  }
}

@tailrec
final def fn2(str: String): Option[String] = {
  Option(str).filter(_.nonEmpty) match {
    case None    => None
    case Some(v) => fn2(v.drop(1))
  }
}
```

However @tailrec only works in second case, in the first case it will generate the following error:

> Error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method fn: it contains a
>   recursive call not in tail position
>         Option(str).filter(_.nonEmpty).flatMap { v =>

Why this error was given? And why these 2 codes generate different kinds JVM bytecode

Comment: Presumably because in the case of "fn" the compiler believes it needs to "flatten" the result of fn(v.drop(1)) before returning it up the call stack. In the second case, it does not need to do further process the result of fn2(v.drop(1))

Comment: @rmathews7 Nope, it's just that `tailrec` doesn't work on mutually recursive functions.

Answer (score 4):

For `fn` to be tail-recursive, the recursive call must be the last action in the function. If you pass `fn` to another function such as `flatMap` then the other function is free to perform other actions after calling `fn` and therefore the compiler cannot be sure that it is tail recursive.

In some cases the compiler could detect that calling `fn` is the last action in the other function, but not in the general case. And this would rely on a specific implementation of that other function so the `tailrec` annotation might become invalid if that other function were changed, which is an undesirable dependency.

Comment: Indeed. The compiler may still be able to optimize the call, but the `@tailrec` annotation makes a very specific promise that the call will be optimized under any possible circumstance, and in order to guarantee that for all possible implementations, there is a very specific set of rules laid out in the Scala Language Specification as to *which* calls are considered tail-recursive calls by the SLS. A compiler may very well optimized *more* calls than the spec forces it to, but the spec is conservative because it has to take account compilers for "hostile" environments such as the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for the last question:

> And why these 2 codes generate different kinds JVM bytecode

Because on JVM there's no guarantee that the JAR containing `Option` class at runtime is the same as was seen at compile-time. This is good, because otherwise even minor versions of libraries (including standard Java and Scala libraries) would be incompatible, and you'd need all dependencies to be using the same minor version of their common dependencies.

If that class doesn't have a suitable `flatMap` method, you'll get `AbstractMethodError`, but otherwise semantics of Scala require that its `flatMap` method must be called. So the compiler has to emit bytecode to actually call the method.

Kotlin works around this by using [`inline` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) and Scala 3 [will support them too](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/inline.html), but I don't know if it'll use them for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
List('a', 'b').flatMap(List(_,'g'))  //res0: List[Char] = List(a, g, b, g)
```

I seems pretty obvious that `flatMap()` is doing some internal post-processing in order to achieve that result. How else would `List('a','g')` get combined with `List('b','g')`?

Comment: That's true for List.flatMap, but not Option.flatMap.